# What's the best way to get rid of no-inner-declaratioins eslint error?

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm working on a typescript codebase that uses modules in this way.

```js
export module Foo {

    const foos = []

    export function getFoos() {
        return getLastFoo();
    }

    function getLastFoo() {
        return foos[-1]
    }
}
```

Screenshot of error:

[image]

I'm trying to get rid of the no-inner-declarations eslint error. One way I thought of was replacing the modules with classes.

```js
export class Foo {

    static foos = []

    static getFoos() {
        return this.getLastFoo();
    }

    private static getLastFoo() {
        return this.foos[-1]
    }
}
```

Is there a way to resolve this eslint error without having to change the modules to classes?

Comment: Don't use `export module Foo`. You should use `module` only in declaration files. If you want to group functions, use classes or just export each function separately

Comment: Why use `module` only in declaration files? What's the logic?

Comment: Coming back to this 1 year later :P